# Initializing ArrayList with user-created objects/input from console

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, arraylist, input

```
import java.util.*
public class InheritancePart1
{   
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    dates.set(0, (1, 12, 1998));
    //Syntax error on token ",", Name expected after this token
}
```

For this program, I have a Date object defined by (int m, int d, int y) so for 
    example (1, 1, 2000), and a subclass of Date called LongDate which is defined by
    (String monthName, int d, int y) so for example ("January", 1, 2000). For sake of simplicity, I have omitted both of these classes and just shown the main method.

My problem is that I need to create an Array of type Date, and then populate that
    array with several Date and LongDate objects, and then invoke methods on these 
    objects. But when I try to assign an object of the Date class to an index of the 
    ArrayList, I get the error message as shown above.

Any ideas for why this is happening/what I'm doing wrong? I tried doing

```
    dates.set(0, Date(1, 12, 1998));
```

but I got the same error message. Also, I tried to initialize it using Scanner, but 
    that didn't work, giving me the same error message.

If anyone could help me out on all these things I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Use `dates.add(new Date(year, month, date));`.

Comment: thank you! i wasn't sure of the syntax, but this helped

Comment: Object creation is really basic stuff. I'd suggest that you refer to the [Objects tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the constructor as

```
new Date(year, month date)
```

Also, note that you want to use `List.add` rather than `List.set`, since you are adding, not replacing elements:

```
dates.add(new Date(year, month, date));
```

Note that the parameters `year` and `month` are probably not what you expect (it is a *ridiculously* poor API) - `year` is the number of years since 1900; `month` is zero-based, so January is zero. As such, you'd need to use:

```
dates.add(new Date(1998 - 1900, 12 - 1, 1));
```

to create a date representing the 1st of December 1998.

Comment: well i have methods in the LongDate and Date classes to deal with that. year, month, and day aren't from java.util.date, they're from input. I'll take an object from this array and pass it to a method that treats 1998 as 1998, not as what the API says.

Comment: Well, that's confusing. You are importing `java.util.Date` (via the wildcard), and not specifying that you have your own `Date` class.

Comment: I just did that because I was lazy. In reality I only needed ArrayList and Scanner. I fixed it though, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You are using a List of dates, so you need to use the  method `add(...)` and passing as a parameter an instance of the date Class..

So your code is not working because you are trying to put in a list something weird that is not even an instance of the Date class... YOU ARE BREAKING the contract between what the list holds and what you are inserting into it...

the solution is adding a valid Date Object...

## Example using the Calendar class:

```
List<Date> myDateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
myDateList.add(new Date());
final Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c1.set(2014, 3, 30); // March 30th 2014
// Date sDate = c1.getTime();
myDateList.add(c1.getTime());

        // print it
        for (final Date d : myDateList) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
```

Comment: NB: don't prefix months/days with `0` - you'll hit problems because that's actually an octal literal.